# MediaPlayer not playing sound after the screen locked

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, alarmmanager, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm using the `AlarmManager` for playing a sound (with `MediaPlayer`) at a given time.

Unfortunately the `play()` method doesn't seem to work when the phone is locked.

I'm developing on Marshmallow, so I already solved the Doze issues by using `setAlarmClock()` and using a CPU wake lock (the Partial wake lock). The strange thing is that the activity launches over the lockscreen (what it should do) when the alarm fires, but the `play()` method of the `MediaPlayer` doesn't play.
When I rotate the screen, the music starts playing.

How can I solve this, so the music start playing when the activity is launched, altough the phone is locked?

Answer (score -1):

Because of the [Dose Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html?hl=ru). When you rotate a screen Dose mode is disabled. Try to add your app in white list

Comment: Isn't there another way? The Alarm app from Google isn't in the white list and uses the same `setAlarmClock()` method. [See line 255](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/marshmallow-release/src/com/android/deskclock/alarms/AlarmStateManager.java)

Comment: "When you rotate a screen Dose mode is disabled" - What does this mean?